# Multiple class using ngClass - Angular 6

Tags: html, angular

When I have only one condition i.e `'e-card horCard card-OK': var1 == 0` ng multiple class works. 
When I have other conditions below, using the same classes `'e-card horCard card-NOK': var1 > 0` as in the first part of the condition, they simply do not apply them. What is a problem here?

```
  <div [ngClass]="{'e-card horCard card-OK': var1 == 0, 'e-card horCard card-NOK': var1 > 0}">
      <div class="card-header">{{'SitesWithProblem' | translate | uppercase}}</div>
      <div class="card-data">{{globalStatistic.TotalSitesWithProblem}}</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same class for both condition so for second condition it is showing only different class from first condition so use below way only needed class as per condition

```
<div class="e-card horCard " [ngClass]="{' card-OK': var1 == 0, 'card-NOK': var1 > 0}">
  <div class="card-header">{{'SitesWithProblem' | translate | uppercase}}</div>
  <div class="card-data">{{globalStatistic.TotalSitesWithProblem}}</div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="e-card horCard " [ngClass]="(var1 == 0)? 'card-OK' : 'card-NOK'">
  <div class="card-header">{{'SitesWithProblem' | translate | uppercase}}</div>
  <div class="card-data">{{globalStatistic.TotalSitesWithProblem}}</div>
</div>
```